# Pug cannot find installed Highlight.js JSTransformer filter

Tags: pug, template-engine, highlight.js

[The documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html) says I just have to install the filters via `npm` in order to use them.

> If you want to be able to use filters in your Pug template, you would first make sure that these features are installed:
>
> ```
> $ npm install --save jstransformer-filter
> ```
>
> Now, you should be able to render the following template:
>
> ```
> :markdown-it(linkify)
>   # Markdown
> ```

I tried this with `highlight.js`:

```
$ npm install --save jstransformer-highlight2
```

But when I compile the pug file:

```
:highlight.js(lang='c')
  int f(int x) {
      return x + 1;
  }
```

I get unknown filter errors:

```
unknown filter ":highlight"
```

I checked [the filter source code](https://github.com/jstransformers/jstransformer-highlight/blob/master/index.js) and confirmed the filter's name is `highlight.js`. I also tried `highlight`, `highlightjs` and `highlight-js`, to no avail.

How do I make this work?

Do I have to pass an option to the pug compiler? [The API documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html) says it's for custom filters only.

Comment: Wow. Looks like the documentation is showing that error on their examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the Webpack to compile Pug templates, then try to use the modern [webdiscus/pug-loader](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader) or the [pug-plugin](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-plugin).

This loader and plugin supports the [:highlight](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader#highlight) and the [:markdown](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader#markdown) filters "out of the box".

You can see the demo seites with examples:

- [how to use the `:highlight` filter with prismjs](https://webdiscus.github.io/pug-loader/pug-filters/highlight.html)
- [how to use the `:markdown` filter](https://webdiscus.github.io/pug-loader/pug-filters/markdown.html)

Comment: I'm not using webpack. I wrote [my own tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-simple) to render my static site. Due to what it says in the docs, ocumentation, I expected to be able to just install the dependency and start using the filter in the templates with no extra steps necessary.